# Eclipse: Using already existing workspace on another PC

Tags: eclipse, workspace

*First off: I thought this was a common problem and searched it but I did not find anything helpful. Maybe I'm unlucky. Sorry if it has been asked many times already.*

**Hey.** I'm currently studying Java and I keep my laptop with me to school and I have my workspace on my Google Drive, which saves all my progress if my computer would break down.

Now whenever I'm home and want/need to work on any of my schoolprojects I wish to use that same workspace (why would I want duplicates that are not even in sync) but its empty when I choose that folder as workspace on my desktop computer.

If I import projects (to the same workspace..) using it as rootfolder (cause then my projects appear in the projects found-list) it says it's all in there already (Project already exist) so I cannot add it to the "current workspace", but that all makes sense.

I believe the eclipse-made-folder in the workspace-folder should help me by setting some settings and helping my desktop-eclipse to work out what is going on in that folder, but it does not, in fact it might be doing the exact opposite.

How do you, if you do, make it work with the same workspace on more than one computer?

Comment: Try refreshing the workspace `File > Refresh`

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. It does refresh, but nothing happens.. :(

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve?

Comment: No I didnt... I have been changing the SDK locations each time i switch computer. If I on my mac has user/library/java then I change that in the settings, to C:/Program/Java thats as far as I know the most simple way.